# How can i review my keypress (detailed undo) in VIM?

Tags: vim

I did some keypress in vim ,left interesting effect. 
I cant reproduce.
How can i figure out what key i pressed? 
I can undo/redo, but is vim storing my keypress in a single undo change?

Comment: What is the effect that you got? Most experts would be able to tell you what you did. :)

Comment: 600 number is decremented to 599. But surely i didnt wrote 599 by hand

Answer (score 4):

you typed control X.

```
Adding and subtracting
                        *CTRL-A*
CTRL-A          Add [count] to the number or alphabetic character at
                or after the cursor.  {not in Vi}

                        *CTRL-X*
CTRL-X          Subtract [count] from the number or alphabetic
                character at or after the cursor.  {not in Vi}
```

go look `:he CTRL-X`.

About reviewing old keypresses, I'm not sure there's such a feature in vim. But I'd think something could be hacked out of https://github.com/fabi1cazenave/autoSession.vim or you could store last command sequence using hook functions, but I'm not sure which ones.

for complex commands, you can still use `:set showcmd` (`:he showcmd`) to see the key you're typing while you're typing them… Not exactly what you ask, but the closest builtin feature I can think of.

Comment: Really i pressed, CTRL-X. 
I intend pressing CTRL-X F for filename completion.

Comment: of course, but you were not in insert mode, but in normal mode! C-x F works in insert mode for completion, whereas C-x in normal mode is a modifier.